# Наплывание нового контента в div

Tags: html, css, анимация, css-animation, anime.js

Необходимо чтобы при клике в блоке наплывало сверху новое содержимое с текстом **"Generating"**, а затем контент с текстом **"Done"** и возврат к исходному состоянию.

Я попробовал изменять цвет фона с помощью псевдо селектора **:after**, изменяя его высоту от 0 до 100%. Но проблема с таким подходом в том, что так я могу сделать только **1 переход**, а мне нужно сделать **2 перехода** и потом вернуть в исходное состояние.

Я это делаю в проекте **vue**, также есть библиотека анимации **anime.js**, возможно эта информация будет полезна.

Ниже приведён прототип как это должно выглядеть.

[image: Прототип анимации]

Comment: помимо псевдо селектора :after, есть еще псевдо селектор :before

Comment: Как я понял вариант через псевдо селекторы не подойдёт поскольку в конце нужно вернуть в исходное состояние также с анимацией сверху вниз. К тому же это не гибкое решение, потому что количество шагов может измениться.